# Error Unparseable date: "00:00:00"

Tags: android, json, api

Estoy desarrollando una `app` la cual utiliza una `api` que conecta a mi `bd`, donde intento pasar un objeto que tiene un parámetro de tipo `Time` el cual me almacena una hora con el formato `hh:mm:ss 00:00:00`. Hasta ahí no tengo inconveniente ya q envio el objeto a mi `bd` por medio de un `json` y lo almacena perfectamente. El tema esta cuando intento traer una lista de esos objetos por medio de un `GET` un ejemplo objeto/getAll, es allí donde me encuentro con el problema que me devuelve el siguiente error `Unparseable date: "02:00:00"`. Sin embargo cuando hago el `GET` usando `PostMan` me trae la lista perfectamente. Alguien puede orientarme?...

Comment: y cual es el código, agregalo por favor.

Comment: si consideramos el error Unparseable date: "02:00:00" resulta que **"02:00:00"** no es una fecha de modo que tiene sentido recibir un **Unparseable date**, probablemente puedas solucionarlo retornando una fecha válida sea 0000-00-00T02:00:00 o 0001-01-01T02:00:00 de la cual solo tomarás el dato de la hora..

Comment: @JonnathanQ pero si yo en mi `bd` tengo una columna `horaActivacion` de tipo `Time` que guarda una hora `02:00:00` sin fecha, como hago para sortear el error si yo solo estoy trayendo un valor?

Comment: @Germanccho el servicio independientemente de que la base base de datos solo retorne una cadena con la hora debe devolver un formato fecha válido, tendrías entonces en el servicio que concatenar o completar la cadena agregando la parte de la fecha de modo que se retorne el dato en formato yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss  o la otra solución es que ese campo en el servicio simplemente de declare como cadena y no como fecha ni hora, así en android no se hará una conversión a un objeto date que es lo que causa el problema